# RXJS - Transforming an array of items, with operators

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I've been struggling for a few hours, I am trying to grasp more advanced concepts, I thought I could use a `reduce` operator for this, but I'd like to resort to another opinion.

The following code loops manually through a returned array of items, inside a tap, I've used `of` just to simulate what the observable would emit.

What I'd like to achieve is to remap each object inside `arrayItems` to have an additional property, and the end result to be an array of objects.

My objective here is to ditch the tap, as I feel there are more efficient ways...

```
        of([{ foo: 'bar' }, { foo: 'baz' }])
            .pipe(
                tap((arrayItems) => {
                    const arr = [];

                    arrayItems.forEach((item) => {
                        arr.push({
                            ...item,
                            extraProperty: {}
                        });
                    });

                    return of(arr);
                })
            )
            .subscribe();
```

If anyone can give me a pointer, I'll be very grateful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tap` operator doesn't modify your value. it is done to do side effects. Instead, use `map` to convert the event:

```
 of([{ foo: 'bar' }, { foo: 'baz' }])
            .pipe(
                map((arrayItems) => 
                    arrayItems.map((item) => ({
                        ...item,
                        extraProperty: {}
                    })
                );
            )
            .subscribe();
```